# Возможность вызвать метод из вью

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Возможно ли вызывать метод с# из представления?

Например:

Есть большая табличка(2) с id пользователя и датами, во вью 2 дропбокса

1. id пользователя
2. даты из таблицы 2

Охото сделать после выбора пользователя, запускался код, который выбирает нужные даты из большой таблицы (по выбранному в 1 дропбоксе пользователю) и подставляет в дропбокс 2

UPD Пример: После выбора пользователя(см. скриншот  поле - 1), загружается список дат у этого пользователя из другой таблицы(см. скриншот  поле - 2)

[image: Пример: После выбора пользователя(см. скриншот поле - 1), загружается список дат у этого пользователя из другой таблицы(см. скриншот поле - 2)]

Answer (score 3):

Если речь идет об MVC модели, то вопрос решается созданием контроллера.

```
public ActionResult Index(string SearchStringID)
{
    var Users = from users in db.Users
    select users;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
    {
        Users = Users.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(SearchStringID));
    }
    return View(Users.ToList());
}
```

примерно так должно быть(кроме имен, конечно)

Comment: Да примерно это и нужно! Я так понимаю, что индекс принимает ID пользователя и возвращает, то что нужно. А как этот метод будет вызываться после выбора имени?

Comment: Про выбор имени не понял.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, добавил пример с скриншотом, надеюсь понятно объяснил

Comment: а, так это в запросе просто просишь вернуть список дат и выведешь.

Вот гайд по поиску в asp.net
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-search

Comment: Но дак это же поиск - фильтр. Мне нужно почти тоже самое, но без кнопки фильтр. Т е событие при смене дропбокса.